# Is the 2 months cooling off period mandatory for a 120 days work permit followed by a L permit for Switzerland?

Tags: switzerland

Let's say that the 120 days work permit is approved by authorities but a project requires the person to continue after 120 days, as well without any gap. So in that case, is it really mandatory to have 2 months cooling off period for the 120 days permit to be followed by a L permit?

Comment: It's not an issue of just 2 months. 120-day permit is for work up to 120 days *per 12-month period*.

Comment: L permit is "short term permit". If you need more time, you must select a different permit.. In any case, this is not about travel

Answer (score 1):

A 120-day L permit is designed to allow up to 120 days of work in Switzerland in any 12-month period. It is for short-term workers exempt from the quota.

You cannot obtain another 120-day permit if you have already used up 120 days in the previous 12-month period. Some cantons may be more lenient if there is actual exceptional circumstances or particularities, but you can't count on it.

You may obtain another short-term permit (usually less than 4 months) after a two-month cooling off period.

You can also obtain without a gap a year-long L permit, but that will be subject to the quota.

Comment: Thank you for your reply !.  if I look at your sentence "You can also obtain without a gap an year-long L permit, but that will be subject to the quota".- so (for Non-EU person) you are saying if you have quota then without cooling off period you can switch to L permit from 120 days permit. but for Non-EU person generally it is a rule that 2 months cooling period is needed when you switch from 120 days permit to L permit though you have quota. what is your say on this?